# How to change css rules of a sibling element when one is on focus?

Tags: css

How to change css rules of a sibling element when one is on focus?

So the idea is to make the opacity of `img` 0.5 when the `input[type="text"]` is on focus.

How can I do that?

```css
#search img {
  width: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0.64rem;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#search input[type="text"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.64rem 0;
}

#search input[type="text"]:focus+img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <img src="assets/search-ico.svg" alt="search" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Products" />
</div>
```

Comment: With your current markup it's impossible (CSS has just next sibling (it's `+` selector, or all next siblings - `~`), not previous one). Change order in your HTML markup to `<input><img>`, than your CSS selector will work.

Comment: If so then the layout changes. There is no other way around?

Comment: Change the order in your markup, then change "visually" the order using flex-direction